# Accessing file from package

Tags: java, file

suppose I put a file a.txt in package com.xyz and the try access it like following. Will it work?

Hi All,

```
          import com.xyz.*;
          public class Hello
          { 
            File f = new File("a.txt");
             ...
          }
```

It is not working for me. Is there any workaround?

Comment: what is not working? stack trace? what do you expect your code to do? are you aware as to what path would this file be created at?

Comment: @Scorpion : a.text file has already created in the com.xyz package and Can't able to access with the file using File f=new File("a.txt");How can i access it?

Comment: i agree with pratik answer by importing package you can refer the classes from that package. If the class file that you are using to do above mentioned actions and txt file are both in same folder or package then it works otherwise you need to give file path

Comment: @Sarvanan   Is there a stack trace available? Have you created a jar with the package in question? Is the file available as is on the file system or is it a part of the jar? How are you running this code? java -cp xyz.jar Hello? A few more details would help

Comment: @Deep Kapadia: I didn't created any jar with the package. "a.txt" is available on the file system.my class file is located in different package. I have just run the code by java Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your responses to the comments above. If you are looking for a work around, just specify the path to the .txt file on the file system. Putting it in a package does not help.

`new File ("a.txt")`

looks for a file on the the file system and not within a package.

Please also read the javadocs on File: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

However I do not see the rationale in putting the file inside a package unless you would want to use it as a resource. In which case @jcomeau_ictx has the right solution

Comment: Note that if this file is an 'application resource' it will generally be inside a Jar file at time of deployment.  In that case, creating a `File` object will not work.

Comment: OK.  Deep already mentioned that - I just wanted to put it in different words.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Class.getResource()` or `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. see for example the Sun demo source at http://jc.unternet.net/src/java/com/sun/WatermarkDemo/WatermarkDemo.java

Answer (score 2):

I will offer the same answer as jcomeau_ictx, but a lot shorter (around 30 lines in one file as opposed to >380 in 1 source file of 5), ..and with a screenshot.  ;)

[image: Get Resource]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

class GetResource {

  GetResource() {
    Class cl = this.getClass();
    final URL url = cl.getResource( cl.getName() + ".java" );
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
        try {
          ep.setPage(url);
          JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ep);
          sp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400,196));
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null,
            e.getMessage() + "  See trace for details.");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GetResource();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on your class path of java from where you can run this class. If both are in same place then it will work. Then no need to define path in file. But the file was not in the classpath dir then must be define path of that file otherwise file not found.